# What does the source code attribute VB_VarMemberFlags do in VBA (if anything at all)?

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

VB6 had some source code attributes visible only when one exported the module to a text file.  An example would be to set the `DispID` to 0 for a default or -4 for an For Each enumerator.  VBA has theoretically the same but sometimes they have no effect in VBA.

What does `VB_VarMemberFlags` do in VBA?  I know its an attribute for a module level variable.  I have seen in some old source code some typical values of 200 or 40 but does this affect anything in VBA?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648764/what-does-the-attribute-keyword-do-in-vb6  which doesn't seem to mention this particular attribute for some reason.

Comment: @DaveInCaz: thanks for linking question (it's good that now it will appear top of the list of questions down the right hand column).  A full list of similar reserved keywords can be found on page 37 of the VBA language specification, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear nothing in VBA.  It's for VB6 and records the checkboxes in the Advanced section of the Procedure Attributes dialog box.  For posterity,

- `Hide this member` = VB_VarMemberFlags = "40"
- `User Interface Default` = VB_VarMemberFlags = "200"
- `Don't show in Property Browser` = VB_VarMemberFlags = "400"

The bottom two only impact in VB6 environment I think.

In constrast `Hide this member` has an external impact for a type library.  `Hide this member` on a method will apply the `hidden` IDL attribute (but VBA users browsing the library can still see by using the `Show hidden members` menu option).

In summary, nothing to see.